# How to pass PassportJS message to React frontend in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have been working with `passport-local` for user authentication and have been struggling in sending custom messages like "Username doesn't exist" or "Password doesn't match" from the server to the React frontend.

```js
const user = await User.findOne({ email });
if (!user) {
  console.log("No user`");
  return done(null, false, {
    message: "User with this email ID doesn't exist",
  });
}
```

The current method I have is a very hacky one and just passes the `passport.authenticate` function inside an express function.

```js
authRouter.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    const error = err as Error;
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }

    if (info) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: info.message });
    }

    req.logIn(user, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
      }

      return res.json(user);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Is there a better way to do this? I also tried using `connect-flash` with passport but wasn't able to quite get it working.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    console.log("No user`");
    return done(null, false, {
      message: "User with this email ID doesn't exist",
    });
  }

authRouter.post("/login", passport.authenticate( "local", {
  successReturnToOrRedirect: "Your_route",
  failureRedirect: "/login",
  failureMessage: true,
}))
))
```

and when you want send failure message to backend:

```
if (req.session.messages) {
  //you can send req.session.message[0]   
}
```

if you have session-express,you should delete session after sending `req.session.message[0]`:

```
  delete req.session.messages
  req.session.save()
```

Comment: I tried the `failureMessage` property but it didn't work. I am using React as the frontend in my case. And how do you set `messages` in `req.session`? Right now I don't see any such property in it

Comment: Unfortunately, I use these codes in the backend

Comment: Do you have a frontend? What is it made with?

Comment: I use `ejs` in frontend,Messages sets here `done(null, false, {
      message: "User with this email ID doesn't exist",
    });`